# Shiny startup button changes working directory

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

When I run shiny app from RStudio editor button "Run App", RStudio (or shiny) set the directory, which is not specified in my code or RStudio:

```
shiny:runApp('~/Desktop')
```

In Tools->Global Options->R General I have a home directory. The working directory of my project and session is my project directory. If I run shiny in console with `shiny::shinyAppDir` or `shiny::runApp` it launches with the directory I set it up, but if I press the "Run App" button, it runs in the Desktop directory.

Strangely, the other day "Run App" button started the app not in Desktop, but in yet another directory inside my project. It seems there is some default for the button, but I cannot find it.

How to specify or change the option to run shiny app from "Run App" button?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. The files were located in ~/Desktop directory, where I copied them by mistake and opened from there. It's really hard to figure out by name of the tab.